# Partial derivatives and chain rule explanation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a function $w=f(x,y)$, where $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ and I'm asked to show that $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial{r}}\cos{\theta}-\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{\theta}}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}$$

I'm not having any trouble with how to tackle the problem. It's very straight forward and I reached a solution, but when I checked the solutions, it had the following line - at this point in the solution, we are after $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}$:

\begin{align*}
\tan\theta&=\frac{y}{x}\\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\sec^{2}\theta&=\frac{-y}{x^{2}}
\end{align*}

I get that the right hand side is the partial with respect to $x$, but my question is, what is going on with the left hand side? Why can one differentiate $\tan\theta$ and also have $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}$?

I'm just after an explanation of this line in the solutions, if possible. I'd really like to understand it properly. Many thanks for your time and patience. I checked quite a few of the suggested questions, but none seemed to contain the question I have (sorry if this is a duplicate).

Comment: Chain rule.  $\theta $ depends on x. Thus you have $\frac{ \partial (tan(\theta (x))}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta }{\theta x} sec^2(\theta)$

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much @calculus